# Django 1.5 - CreateView Not Creating / Saving New Model

Tags: django, django-views

I'm trying to wrap my head around CBVs.  Here I'm using the CreateView to provide my template a form for creating new models (via POST).  When I provide the form with valid data, it submits and returns back to the same page as if the form had errors, but it does't.  No errors are displayed when the page refreshes after the HTTP POST.  I know the validation works because I've test scenarios where I don't provide some data at the appropriate form field has an error message associated with it.  I check the database and no record was inserted.  My database is configured properly.  I have other parts of the app reading from it.  The database also has all the current migrations applied to it via South.

I'm hoping someone can shed some light on what seems to be a simple fundamental setup of a CBV.

Thanks in advance.

**models.py**

```
class Guide(models.Model):
    DIFFICULTY_OPTIONS = (
        (u'1', u'Easy'),
        (u'2', u'So so'),
        (u'3', u'Moderate'),
        (u'4', u'Challenging'),
        (u'5', u'Very challenging'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)    
    difficulty = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=DIFFICULTY_OPTIONS, default=u'1', null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now(), editable=False)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
    publish = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    delete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**forms.py**

```
class NewGuideForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(widget=forms.widgets.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Title',
                                                              'class': 'input-block-level'}))
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder': 'Description',
                                                           'rows': 8,
                                                           'class': 'input-block-level'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Guide
        exclude = ('user', 'slug', 'created', 'modified', 'publish', 'delete', 'modified',)
```

**views.py**

```
class NewGuideView(CreateView):

    model = Guide
    form_class = NewGuideForm
    template_name = "guides/guide_new.html"
    success_url = "/" # Just to keep things simple, redirect to root.

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(NewGuideView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        try:
            Guide.objects.get(title=form.title)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return super(NewGuideView, self).form_valid(form)
        return super(NewGuideView, self).form_invalid(form)
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^guides/new/$', guide.NewGuideView.as_view(), name='guide-new'),
```

**guides/guide_new.html**

```
...
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    <p>First, let's start by entering a title.</p>
    <p>{{ form.title.errors }}</p>
    <p>{{ form.title }}</p>
    <p>Now, provide a short summary of the problem you will be solving.</p>
    <p>{{ form.description.errors }}</p>
    <p>{{ form.description }}</p>
    <p>On a scale of 1 to 5, 5 being the most difficult, how hard is this?</p>
    <p>{{ form.difficulty.errors }}</p>
    <p>{{ form.difficulty }}</p>
    <button type="submit" class="btn-password btn btn-send">Submit</button>
</form>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should refer to `title` field as `form.cleaned_data['title']` rather than `form.title`. The submitted valid field values are in `form.cleaned_data` dict.

So change your code as

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    try:
        Guide.objects.get(title=form.cleaned_data['title'])
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return super(NewGuideView, self).form_valid(form)
    return super(NewGuideView, self).form_invalid(form)
```

Assessing `form.title` will result in `AttributeError` which is not handled in your method.

Comment: Yeah, that was an error of mine - a result of late night coding.  However, after correcting that, I still haven't been able to get past my problem.  I placed a print statement right in the opening line of my form_valid method and nothing is printed.  So it's not even being called.

Comment: @DanielMartin, line in urls.py `guide.NewGuideView.as_view()` does not seem appropriate. I don't think it needs `guide.`.

Comment: I have my views split into different modules for orginization purposes.  So, I have a "views" folder with an __init__.py defined, which imports the different view modules.  I know this isn't the issue.  Back to my CBV, NewGuideView, if I put a print statement inside of the overridden dispatch method, stuff get printed.  For whatever reason, the form_valid is not getting invoked.

Comment: I'm trying to do the exact same thing (save for the splitted views) with Django 1.5.1 and I can't get form_valid called..